# Disable Zoom on new Google Maps Engine

Tags: html, google-maps, maps, scroll, zooming

I'm trying to disable the scrolling/zooming in and out aspect of this page:

http://s1magazine.co.uk/NSA/pages/services/

Everytime I scroll past it it it just zooms in, how can I disable it?

```
<h2>NSA is a national competition happening throughout England.</h2>
<h2><!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<!-- Responsive iFrame --></h2>
<div class="Flexible-container"><iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?    mid=zyaBPLJJ7er8.kdbvNz_CrEYk" height="350" width="425" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Did you managed to fix this???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable mouse scroll wheel zoom on embedded Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps)

Answer (score 2):

The better way to custom google maps is to work directly with the google maps api.
For the specific case, you can set the **scrollwheel** false in the **map options** and disable the scrolling/zooming

```
<style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px
    }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false  
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>


<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "Map iFrame" or "API", I've made a plugin that I use for solve this issue. Can you check it in https://github.com/diazemiliano/googlemaps-scrollprevent

**Here's some example.**

```js
(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#btn-start").click(function() {
      $("iframe[src*='google.com/maps']").scrollprevent({
        printLog: true
      }).start();
      return $("#btn-stop").click(function() {
        return $("iframe[src*='google.com/maps']").scrollprevent().stop();
      });
    });
    return $("#btn-start").trigger("click");
  });
}).call(this);
```

```css
Edit in JSFiddle Result JavaScript HTML CSS .embed-container {
  position: relative !important;
  padding-bottom: 56.25% !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
.embed-container iframe {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
.mapscroll-wrap {
  position: static !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/diazemiliano/googlemaps-scrollprevent/v.0.6.5/dist/googlemaps-scrollprevent.min.js"></script>
<div class="embed-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d12087.746318586604!2d-71.64614110000001!3d-40.76341959999999!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9610bf42e48faa93%3A0x205ebc786470b636!2sVilla+la+Angostura%2C+Neuqu%C3%A9n!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sar!4v1425058155802"
  width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
<p><a id="btn-start" href="#">"Start Scroll Prevent"</a>  <a id="btn-stop" href="#">"Stop Scroll Prevent"</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Your welcome.
Fell free to post comments or issues via github.