# Google Maps - Lock Position

Tags: google-maps, drupal, maps

I use a content management system  (Drupal) for my work website and I was wondering if there is a way to lock the google map position so it doesn't jar over the place when the user clicks on the balloons? I'm aware that there is a very helpful suggestion here [Disable mouse scroll wheel zoom on embedded Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/is-it-possible-to-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps) but I can't manipulate the Javascript or CSS.

any help you give will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the map being included in the page? A map module?

Comment: general content module. we don't have the map capability

Comment: I could give an example if I knew what code you were using to include the map. If you are using the javascript api, you can set 'draggable' to false on the mapOptions object. You can also set 'maxZoom' and 'minZoom' to effectively disable zooming. All the maoOptions are explained [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a event listener to listen to the event `center_changed`

There is a [sample event example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple) in the documentation where the map listen to the `center_changed` and wait for 3 seconds before it recenter the map.

I think you can implement something similar with no time delay to "Lock" the position of your map.

You can refer to the [documentation regarding to the center_changed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#MarkerEvents) here.

Comment: It would be better to set the 'draggable' parameter to false in the mapOptions object which is why I asked how she is including the map. I could give an example if I knew that.

Comment: Oh... Yea draggable sounds better. Just remember Drupal probably use iframes for google maps... So JavaScript might not work

Comment: Drupal has a few mapping modules including the one I made [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/project/goomap). But it does sound like she is just using an iframe.

Comment: Oh really? it's my bad I totally didn't realized it is actually a Drupal question to begin with :(

Comment: Sorry I went MIA but I don't have access to specific Drupal Map modes. I can only edit the iframe, unfortunately.