# iFrame inside draggable / scrollable area

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, dom-events

I'm stuck at finding a solution to my problem.

Let's assume we have fixed-sized area with scrollbars. We need to place an iframe inside so we can preview it by either using the scrollbars or by dragging it. To prevent iframe capturing mouse events, I've put absolute positioned transparent div above it.

```
<div style="" id="scrolling_container">
 <div id="drag_div"></div>
 <div id="frame_div">
     <iframe id="page_iframe" src="http://www.bbc.com/" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then I used some code that transforms mouse dragging into div scrolling.

```
    var draggableContainer = document.getElementById("drag_div");
    var scrollingContainer = document.getElementById("scrolling_container");
    draggableContainer.removeEventListener('mousedown', draggableContainer.md, 0);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', draggableContainer.mu, 0);
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', draggableContainer.mm, 0);
    var pushed = 0;

    draggableContainer.addEventListener('mousedown',
            draggableContainer.md = function(e) {
                pushed = 1;
                lastClientX = e.clientX;
                lastClientY = e.clientY;

                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                draggableContainer.style.cursor = "move";
            }, 0
    );

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', 
            draggableContainer.mu = function() {
                pushed = 0;
                draggableContainer.style.cursor = "pointer";
            }, 0
    );

    window.addEventListener('mousemove',
            draggableContainer.mm = function(e) {
                if (pushed) {
                    var offsetLeft = - lastClientX + (lastClientX=e.clientX),
                            offsetTop = - lastClientY + (lastClientY=e.clientY);                         
                        scrollingContainer.scrollLeft -= offsetLeft;
                        scrollingContainer.scrollTop -= offsetTop;
                }
            }, 0
    );
```

Please take a look at the demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsgpe6nc/3/)

The problem is, overlay div is not stretched across the whole iframe, it's only spread to visible div area:
[Screenshot](http://ibin.co/2GPTIvTLzjdu)

It works fine though if I delete this

```
#scrolling_container {
    position: relative;
}
```

But I need it to be like that because otherwise overlay div overlaps scrollbars and I can no longer use them.

Is there any cross-browser solution that prevents iframe from capturing mouse events so I could get rid of overlay div?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable any mouse interaction with the iframe if you give it the `pointer-events:none;` property in CSS.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware but it's not fully cross-browser. It's supported by IE11+ which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#drag_div {
   background:transparent; 
   position:relative; 
   width:100%;
   height:480px; /* your iframe height */
   top:480px;  /* your iframe height */
   margin-top:-480px;  /* your iframe height */
}
```

probably check this link

[Disable mouse scroll wheel zoom on embedded Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps)