# How to disable scrolling for an iframe in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

http://www.mbe-martinique.fr/emballage-et-expedition/suivi-colis

I have used the scrolling attribute, which works for Firefox but not for chrome. I have also used overflow:hidden css, but it doesn't seem to work either.

A vertical scroll bar is not seen, but the iframe scrolls vertically on mouse-wheel, which is exactly what i want to disable.

Kindly suggest as to how I move forward!

Comment: A combination of [HTML iframe - disable scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll) and [Disable mouse scroll wheel zoom on embedded Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps) will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try to hidden the scroll bar with parent element like this example:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

iframe {
  border: none;
  width: calc(100% + 16px);
  height: calc(100% + 16px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <iframe src="https://fiddle.jshell.net"></iframe>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Lf85aLry/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Add scrolling="no" to your iframe tag: