# "Scroll to the element" javascript won't work on my website. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I took this bootstrap template below to develop my own website. Everything worked but the "scroll to the element script". I keep getting this error:
**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#],[data-toggle],[data-target],[data-slide]**
I think this particular piece of code is deprecated, it woos good with JQuery 2x but not with the new ones. Could someone help me change this script to make it work?

> // Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
>       $(function() {
>           $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#],[data-toggle],[data-target],[data-slide])').click(function() {
>               if (location.pathname.replace(/^//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
>                   var target = $(this.hash);
>                   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
>                   if (target.length) {
>                       $('html,body').animate({
>                           scrollTop: target.offset().top
>                       }, 1000);
>                       return false;
>                   }
>               }
>           });
>       });
>   `

Here's the whole soursecode:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Stylish Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
<nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#top" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Start Bootstrap</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#top" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#services" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#portfolio" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
<header id="top" class="header">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">
        <h1>Start Bootstrap</h1>
        <h3>Free Bootstrap Themes &amp; Templates</h3>
        <br>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- About -->
<section id="about" class="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Stylish Portfolio is the perfect theme for your next project!</h2>
                <p class="lead">This theme features some wonderful photography courtesy of <a target="_blank" href="http://join.deathtothestockphoto.com/">Death to the Stock Photo</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>

<!-- Services -->
<!-- The circle icons use Font Awesome's stacked icon classes. For more information, visit http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
<section id="services" class="services bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <h2>Our Services</h2>
                <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-compass fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>

<!-- Callout -->
<aside class="callout">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">
        <h1>Vertically Centered Text</h1>
    </div>
</aside>

<!-- Portfolio -->
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h2>Our Work</h2>
                <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-1.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-2.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-3.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-4.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">View More Items</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>

<!-- Call to Action -->
<aside class="call-to-action bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h3>The buttons below are impossible to resist.</h3>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-light">Click Me!</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark">Look at Me!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>

<!-- Map -->
<section id="contact" class="map">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
    <br />
    <small>
        <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
    </small>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h4><strong>Start Bootstrap</strong>
                </h4>
                <p>3481 Melrose Place
                    <br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210</p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> (123) 456-7890</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i> <a href="mailto:name@example.com">name@example.com</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr class="small">
                <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="to-top" href="#top" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-fw fa-1x"></i></a>
</footer>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script>
// Closes the sidebar menu
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
// Opens the sidebar menu
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
// Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#],[data-toggle],[data-target],[data-slide])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
//#to-top button appears after scrolling
var fixed = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
        if (!fixed) {
            fixed = true;
            // $('#to-top').css({position:'fixed', display:'block'});
            $('#to-top').show("slow", function() {
                $('#to-top').css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    display: 'block'
                });
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (fixed) {
            fixed = false;
            $('#to-top').hide("slow", function() {
                $('#to-top').css({
                    display: 'none'
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
// Disable Google Maps scrolling
// See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25904582/1607849
// Disable scroll zooming and bind back the click event
var onMapMouseleaveHandler = function(event) {
    var that = $(this);
    that.on('click', onMapClickHandler);
    that.off('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
    that.find('iframe').css("pointer-events", "none");
}
var onMapClickHandler = function(event) {
        var that = $(this);
        // Disable the click handler until the user leaves the map area
        that.off('click', onMapClickHandler);
        // Enable scrolling zoom
        that.find('iframe').css("pointer-events", "auto");
        // Handle the mouse leave event
        that.on('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
    }
    // Enable map zooming with mouse scroll when the user clicks the map
$('.map').on('click', onMapClickHandler);
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping `#` with `\\` infront of it, as it is a special character.

```
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#][data-toggle][data-target][data-slide])')
```

This will work!