# Disable the Ctrl + Scroll to Zoom google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does anybody know how to disable the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + `Scroll`?

First when the mouse wheel was moved the Map would Zoom in/out. But now it asks to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Mouse Wheel Scroll to Zoom in/out.

How do we disable this feature? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlOptions

[image]

Comment: this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps

Comment: @BrajeshKanungo that is not related to the above feature - this a new feature introduced by Google Maps - I want to disable it.

Comment: Ok can you tell me which API version you are  using.

Comment: the latest version -https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp

Comment: This has just appeared on our site too, so probably an update on googles API

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You need to pass `gestureHandling: 'greedy'` to your map options.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#gestureHandling

For example:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
  center: { 0, 0 },
  zoom: 4,
  gestureHandling: 'greedy'
});
```

---

**Update!** Since Google Maps `3.35.6` you need to encase the property into an options wrapper:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
  center: { 0, 0 },
  zoom: 4,
  options: {
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  }
});
```

*Thank you `ealfonso` for the new info*

Comment: @DiegoAndrade I'm not aware of the details. maybe it wasn't implemented back then. But it's present on versions `3.29` (frozen), `3.30` (release) and upwards (`3.exp`, experimental).

Comment: Yes @Kano, in these docs this feature is still present, but on my tests here it is not working. I really don't know why they removed this :(

Comment: They didn't remove it, they added it after version `3.26`. Simply update your script and you're good to go : )

Comment: Yeah, it's working with `3.26`, `3.27`, `3.28` and `3.29`. Starting with `3.30` is does not work anymore. At least for now.

Comment: Sorry @DiegoAndrade but I simply can't agree with you. If you look at this link, then `gestureHandling` is present on all 3 selectable versions (that means `3.29`, `3.30` *and* `3.31`): [See the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference)

Comment: I know it is present. That's the point. Starting with `3.30` It's not working. I tested all these versions. Anyway, it's working by now with `3.26`.

Comment: finally the right answer. Took me a long time googling for this. Why google did't make this the default is beyond me.

Comment: Bingo, this is the perfect solution.

Comment: OK, but there is also the case of the user looking for a browser extension to do the job, if he is unable to contact the map author.

Answer (score 20):

If you're OK with disabling scroll-to-zoom entirely, you can use `scrollwheel: false`. The user will still be able to zoom the map by clicking the zoom buttons if you provide them with the zoom control (`zoomControl: true`).

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference
(search the page for "scrollwheel")

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
  center: { 0, 0 },
  zoom: 4,
  scrollwheel: false,
  zoomControl: true
});
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking to only hide the overlay but still disable the ability to scroll and zoom (like before), you could use CSS to hide the overlay:

```
.gm-style-pbc {
opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Note this will hide it for mobile as well so you could use something like this to ensure it shows "use two fingers to move the map":

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 980px ) {
.gm-style-pbc {
opacity: 0 !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised more people don't want this. It's a *very* distracting overlay message that virtually destroys the map experience for me.

Answer (score 5):

Nesting the `gestureHandling` within an `options` property worked for me on version "3.35.6".

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        options:{
            gestureHandling: 'greedy'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to get the `gestureHandling: 'greedy'` fix to work for me since I had an overlay over the map. I ended up detecting the `mousewheel` event and setting the `ctrl` property to true.

```
// Load maps and attach event listener to scroll event.
var $map = $('.map');
$map[0].addEventListener('wheel', wheelEvent, true);         

function wheelEvent(event) {
    // Set the ctrlKey property to true to avoid having to press ctrl to zoom in/out.
    Object.defineProperty(event, 'ctrlKey', { value: true });
}
```