# JQuery scrolling scrolls randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used a JS script I found on the web. It worked like a charm and suddenly, I don't know why, it doesn't. 
 The problem is that when I click on the buttons "careers" or "contact us" it doesn't scroll to that section and hyperlink is good - it either scrolls randomly or goes to the top.

You can check the online website [here](http://mockup.industrialcons.com/) and here's complete code (original was not edited and it worked fine):

```js
      (function($) {
      "use strict"; // Start of use strict
    
      // Closes the sidebar menu
      $(".menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
        $(".menu-toggle > .fa-bars, .menu-toggle > .fa-times").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
      });
    
      // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
      $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    
      // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
      $('#sidebar-wrapper .js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").removeClass("active");
        $(".menu-toggle").removeClass("active");
        $(".menu-toggle > .fa-bars, .menu-toggle > .fa-times").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
      });
    
      // Scroll to top button appear
      $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollDistance = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrollDistance > 100) {
          $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
          $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
        }
      });
    
    })(jQuery); // End of use strict
    
    // Disable Google Maps scrolling
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25904582/1607849
    // Disable scroll zooming and bind back the click event
    var onMapMouseleaveHandler = function(event) {
      var that = $(this);
      that.on('click', onMapClickHandler);
      that.off('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
      that.find('iframe').css("pointer-events", "none");
    }
    var onMapClickHandler = function(event) {
      var that = $(this);
      // Disable the click handler until the user leaves the map area
      that.off('click', onMapClickHandler);
      // Enable scrolling zoom
      that.find('iframe').css("pointer-events", "auto");
      // Handle the mouse leave event
      that.on('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
    }
    // Enable map zooming with mouse scroll when the user clicks the map
    $('.map').on('click', onMapClickHandler);
```

```css
    body,
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    }
    
    .btn-xl {
      padding: 1.25rem 2.5rem;
    }
    
    .content-section {
      padding-top: 7.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 7.5rem;
    }
    
    .content-section-heading h2 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
    .content-section-heading h3 {
      font-size: 1rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .content-section-contact {
      padding-top: 6.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 6.5rem;
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .text-faded {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
    
    /* Map */
    .map {
      height: 40rem;
    }
    
    .map iframe {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top {
      position: fixed;
      right: 15px;
      bottom: 15px;
      display: none;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5);
      line-height: 45px;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top:focus, .scroll-to-top:hover {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top:hover {
      background: #4a4a4a;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top i {
      font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .masthead {
      min-height: 30rem;
      position: relative;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding-top: 8rem;
      padding-bottom: 8rem;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%), url("../img/bg-masthead.jpg");
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 50% 50%;
    }
    
    .masthead h1 {
      font-size: 4rem;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .masthead {
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .masthead h1 {
        font-size: 5.5rem;
      }
    }
    
    /* Side Menu */
    #sidebar-wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 2;
      right: 0;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      transform: translateX(250px);
      background: #3194f7;
      border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
    
    .flag {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #3194f7;
    }
    
    
    .sidebar-nav-language {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px;
    
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 250px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li.sidebar-nav-item a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li a:active,
    .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.1);
      height: 80px;
      line-height: 50px;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background: none;
    }
    
    #sidebar-wrapper.active {
      right: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    }
    
    .menu-toggle {
      position: fixed;
      right: 15px;
      top: 15px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5);
      line-height: 50px;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .menu-toggle:focus, .menu-toggle:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .menu-toggle:hover {
      background: #343a40;
    }
    
    .callout {
      padding: 15rem 0;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%), url("../img/bg-callou.jpeg");
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .callout h2 {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      display: block;
      max-width: 30rem;
    }
    
    
    footer.footer {
      padding-top: 5rem;
      padding-bottom: 5rem;
    }
    
    footer.footer .social-link {
      display: block;
      height: 4rem;
      width: 4rem;
      line-height: 4.3rem;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      background-color: #3194f7;
      transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    footer.footer .social-link:hover {
      background-color: #155d74;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #3194f7;
    }
    
    a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
      color: #155d74;
    }
    
    
    .btn-primary {
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
      border-color: #1D809F !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    
    .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
      background-color: #155d74 !important;
      border-color: #155d74 !important;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary {
      background-color: #ecb807 !important;
      border-color: #ecb807 !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary:hover, .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary:active {
      background-color: #ba9106 !important;
      border-color: #ba9106 !important;
    }
    
    .btn-dark {
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    
    .btn-through {
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
      border-color: #1D809F !important;
      color: #FFF !important;
      position:relative;
      margin-top: 65%;
      margin-right: 55% !important;
      margin-left: -50%;
      margin-bottom: -20%;
    
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      
      .masthead {
        background-size: 55% 65%;
      }
    
      .btn-through {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 50%;
        margin-bottom: -120%;
        margin-left: -90%;
    
      }
    
    }
    
    .btn-through:hover, .btn-through:active {
        background-color: #1D809F !important;
        border-color: #ecb807 !important;
        color:white !important;
        opacity: 0.9;
      }
    
    .btn {
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .bg-primary {
      background-color: #1D809F !important;
    }
    
    .text-primary {
      color: #1D809F !important;
    }
    
    .text-secondary {
      color: #ecb807 !important;
    }
    
    .text-bold {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fff;
    
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
    
    .margin-left {
      margin-left: 3%;
      margin-top: 3%;
    }
    
    .bg-blue {
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
      <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    
        <title>Industiral Consulting - Industrial Processes</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="css/stylish-portfolio.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
      </head>
    
      <body id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <a class="menu-toggle rounded" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#careers">Careers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li class="list-inline-item margin-left">
                <a href="index.html"><img class="flag" src="img/Britain-flag.png" alt="English"></a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item margin-left">
                <a href="index_de.html"><img class="flag" src="img/Germany-flag.png" alt="German"></a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item margin-left">
                <a href="index_rs.html"><img class="flag" src="img/Serbian-flag.png" alt="Serbian"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    
        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="masthead d-flex">
          <div class="container text-center my-auto">
            <!--<h1 class="mb-1">Industrial Consulting</h1>
            <h3 class="mb-5">
              <em>Industrial Processes</em>
            </h3> -->
          </div>
    
          <div class="container text-center my-auto">
            <a class="btn btn-through btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Find More</a>
          </div>
          
          <div class="overlay">
          </div>
        </header>
        
    
        <!-- About -->
        <section class="content-section" id="about">
          <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <p class="lead mb-5">We are a management consulting firm focused on small and medium-sized businesses, predominantly in metalworking industry. <br>
                  Our approach is to help clients to constantly make better decisions, especially in transition periods. <br>
                  We offer consulting services in areas such as Change Management, Process Optimisation, Production Optimisation and HR Politics. <br> 
                  We are well connected between the German and Serbian market.
                </p>
                <a class="btn btn-dark btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#careers">Careers</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Callout -->
        <section class="callout" id="careers">
          <div class="container text-center">
            <h2 class="mx-auto mb-5 text-bold">Internships and careers:</h2>
            <p class="lead mb-5 text-bold" >If you are interested in working with us and our potential clients from different industries, please send us cv and motivation letter on office@industrialcons.com </p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact Us!</a>
          </div>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Contact us section -->
        <section class="content-section-contact bg-blue bg-primary text-white" id="contact">
          <div class="container text-center bg-blue">
            <h2 class="mb-4">Fruskogorska 29, 21000 Novi Sad, Serbia </h2><br>
            <h2 class="mb-4">Email: office@industrialcons.com</h2>
          </div>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Map -->
        <section class="map">
          <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d5399722.141398233238!2d19.847745025463805!3d45.23487318284108!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x475b100e12212b31%3A0xef7954ac2f396b37!2sFru%C5%A1kogorska+29%2C+Novi+Sad!5e0!3m2!1sen!2srs!4v1524649147292"></iframe>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="footer text-center">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="list-inline mb-5">
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a class="social-link rounded-circle text-white" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/18593992/">
                  <i class="icon-social-linkedin"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-muted small mb-0">Copyright &copy; Industrial Consulting - Industiral Processes</p>
          </div>
        </footer>
    
        <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
        <a class="scroll-to-top rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
        </a>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
        <script src="js/stylish-portfolio.min.js"></script>
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: If the original code used to work fine, then the problem could be a new script file that you added recently that is conflicting with the JQuery code.

Comment: It was working completely with the JQuery code since the beginning. But at the some point of coding (and I was changing only html and css) it just stopped working.

Comment: On link you've provided everything works great

Comment: Please see my answer. Mark is as answer when ready. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works now. I've edited the JQuery click function to call the section it needs to scroll to by it's class.

**Edit:**
The Home click was not working on previous answer. It now works fine. Have moved the Home ID to the header in HTML.

```js
(function($) {
      "use strict"; // Start of use strict
    
      // Closes the sidebar menu
      $(".menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
        $(".menu-toggle > .fa-bars, .menu-toggle > .fa-times").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
      });
    
      // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
      $('js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    
      // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
      $('#sidebar-wrapper .js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").removeClass("active");
        $(".menu-toggle").removeClass("active");
        $(".menu-toggle > .fa-bars, .menu-toggle > .fa-times").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
      });
    
      // Scroll to top button appear
      $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollDistance = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrollDistance > 100) {
          $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
          $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
        }
      });
    
    })(jQuery); // End of use strict
    
    // Disable Google Maps scrolling
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25904582/1607849
    // Disable scroll zooming and bind back the click event
    var onMapMouseleaveHandler = function(event) {
      var that = $(this);
      that.on('click', onMapClickHandler);
      that.off('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
      that.find('iframe').css("pointer-events", "none");
    }
    var onMapClickHandler = function(event) {
      var that = $(this);
      // Disable the click handler until the user leaves the map area
      that.off('click', onMapClickHandler);
      // Enable scrolling zoom
      that.find('iframe').css("pointer-events", "auto");
      // Handle the mouse leave event
      that.on('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
    }
    // Enable map zooming with mouse scroll when the user clicks the map
    $('.map').on('click', onMapClickHandler);
```

```css
body,
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    }
    
    .btn-xl {
      padding: 1.25rem 2.5rem;
    }
    
    .content-section {
      padding-top: 7.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 7.5rem;
    }
    
    .content-section-heading h2 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
    .content-section-heading h3 {
      font-size: 1rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .content-section-contact {
      padding-top: 6.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 6.5rem;
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .text-faded {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
    
    /* Map */
    .map {
      height: 40rem;
    }
    
    .map iframe {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top {
      position: fixed;
      right: 15px;
      bottom: 15px;
      display: none;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5);
      line-height: 45px;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top:focus, .scroll-to-top:hover {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top:hover {
      background: #4a4a4a;
    }
    
    .scroll-to-top i {
      font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .masthead {
      min-height: 30rem;
      position: relative;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding-top: 8rem;
      padding-bottom: 8rem;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%), url("../img/bg-masthead.jpg");
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 50% 50%;
    }
    
    .masthead h1 {
      font-size: 4rem;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .masthead {
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .masthead h1 {
        font-size: 5.5rem;
      }
    }
    
    /* Side Menu */
    #sidebar-wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 2;
      right: 0;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      transform: translateX(250px);
      background: #3194f7;
      border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
    
    .flag {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #3194f7;
    }
    
    
    .sidebar-nav-language {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px;
    
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 250px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li.sidebar-nav-item a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li a:active,
    .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.1);
      height: 80px;
      line-height: 50px;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background: none;
    }
    
    #sidebar-wrapper.active {
      right: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    }
    
    .menu-toggle {
      position: fixed;
      right: 15px;
      top: 15px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5);
      line-height: 50px;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .menu-toggle:focus, .menu-toggle:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .menu-toggle:hover {
      background: #343a40;
    }
    
    .callout {
      padding: 15rem 0;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%), url("../img/bg-callou.jpeg");
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .callout h2 {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      display: block;
      max-width: 30rem;
    }
    
    
    footer.footer {
      padding-top: 5rem;
      padding-bottom: 5rem;
    }
    
    footer.footer .social-link {
      display: block;
      height: 4rem;
      width: 4rem;
      line-height: 4.3rem;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      background-color: #3194f7;
      transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    footer.footer .social-link:hover {
      background-color: #155d74;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #3194f7;
    }
    
    a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
      color: #155d74;
    }
    
    
    .btn-primary {
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
      border-color: #1D809F !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    
    .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
      background-color: #155d74 !important;
      border-color: #155d74 !important;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary {
      background-color: #ecb807 !important;
      border-color: #ecb807 !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary:hover, .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary:active {
      background-color: #ba9106 !important;
      border-color: #ba9106 !important;
    }
    
    .btn-dark {
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    
    .btn-through {
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
      border-color: #1D809F !important;
      color: #FFF !important;
      position:relative;
      margin-top: 65%;
      margin-right: 55% !important;
      margin-left: -50%;
      margin-bottom: -20%;
    
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      
      .masthead {
        background-size: 55% 65%;
      }
    
      .btn-through {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 50%;
        margin-bottom: -120%;
        margin-left: -90%;
    
      }
    
    }
    
    .btn-through:hover, .btn-through:active {
        background-color: #1D809F !important;
        border-color: #ecb807 !important;
        color:white !important;
        opacity: 0.9;
      }
    
    .btn {
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .bg-primary {
      background-color: #1D809F !important;
    }
    
    .text-primary {
      color: #1D809F !important;
    }
    
    .text-secondary {
      color: #ecb807 !important;
    }
    
    .text-bold {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fff;
    
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
    
    .margin-left {
      margin-left: 3%;
      margin-top: 3%;
    }
    
    .bg-blue {
      background-color: #3194f7 !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
      <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    
        <title>Industiral Consulting - Industrial Processes</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="css/stylish-portfolio.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <a class="menu-toggle rounded" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#careers">Careers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
              <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li class="list-inline-item margin-left">
                <a href="index.html"><img class="flag" src="img/Britain-flag.png" alt="English"></a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item margin-left">
                <a href="index_de.html"><img class="flag" src="img/Germany-flag.png" alt="German"></a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item margin-left">
                <a href="index_rs.html"><img class="flag" src="img/Serbian-flag.png" alt="Serbian"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    
        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="masthead d-flex" id="page-top">
          <div class="container text-center my-auto">
            <!--<h1 class="mb-1">Industrial Consulting</h1>
            <h3 class="mb-5">
              <em>Industrial Processes</em>
            </h3> -->
          </div>
    
          <div class="container text-center my-auto">
            <a class="btn btn-through btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Find More</a>
          </div>
          
          <div class="overlay">
          </div>
        </header>
        
    
        <!-- About -->
        <section class="content-section" id="about">
          <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <p class="lead mb-5">We are a management consulting firm focused on small and medium-sized businesses, predominantly in metalworking industry. <br>
                  Our approach is to help clients to constantly make better decisions, especially in transition periods. <br>
                  We offer consulting services in areas such as Change Management, Process Optimisation, Production Optimisation and HR Politics. <br> 
                  We are well connected between the German and Serbian market.
                </p>
                <a class="btn btn-dark btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#careers">Careers</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Callout -->
        <section class="callout" id="careers">
          <div class="container text-center">
            <h2 class="mx-auto mb-5 text-bold">Internships and careers:</h2>
            <p class="lead mb-5 text-bold" >If you are interested in working with us and our potential clients from different industries, please send us cv and motivation letter on office@industrialcons.com </p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact Us!</a>
          </div>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Contact us section -->
        <section class="content-section-contact bg-blue bg-primary text-white" id="contact">
          <div class="container text-center bg-blue">
            <h2 class="mb-4">Fruskogorska 29, 21000 Novi Sad, Serbia </h2><br>
            <h2 class="mb-4">Email: office@industrialcons.com</h2>
          </div>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Map -->
        <section class="map">
          <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d5399722.141398233238!2d19.847745025463805!3d45.23487318284108!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x475b100e12212b31%3A0xef7954ac2f396b37!2sFru%C5%A1kogorska+29%2C+Novi+Sad!5e0!3m2!1sen!2srs!4v1524649147292"></iframe>
        </section>
    
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="footer text-center">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="list-inline mb-5">
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a class="social-link rounded-circle text-white" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/18593992/">
                  <i class="icon-social-linkedin"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-muted small mb-0">Copyright &copy; Industrial Consulting - Industiral Processes</p>
          </div>
        </footer>
    
        <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
        <a class="scroll-to-top rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
        </a>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
        <script src="js/stylish-portfolio.min.js"></script>
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)
I just burned out and needed to someone else look the code. I appreciate it. You got a beer on me

Comment: :) Anytime bud. That's usually the case. A fresh pair of eyes is always good. T