# JavaScript replace mouse events with touch events?

Tags: javascript, iframe, mobile

I have a Webpage with an iFrame showing a Web map.

The user can drag the map with a mouse but not on a mobile device with touch gestures.

My idea is to replace mouse events with the corresponding touch events, is that possible or is there a better way?

Comment: You mean, catch the mouse events and turn around and create touch events?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps

Comment: Kind of, or something like translate mouse events to touch events.